# Printing x amount of times in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print a table in Python, where I want to print the amount of columns needed which depends on the user.

I am asking the user to input a start time and a finish time, as well as how much they want it to increment. Once I get those values, I want to print a table that has the time in the columns, however the number of columns is going to change based on what the user inputs.

What I can't figure out is how print only the amount of columns that are needed.

Below is what I have so far, but it is nowhere near what I want.

```
initial = int(input("Initial investment amount: "))
max_initial = int(input("Maximum initial investment amount: "))
increment_initial = int(input("Value to be used to increment the initial investment amount: "))

min_time = int(input("Minimum time period of investment: "))
max_time = int(input("Maximum time period of investment: "))
increment_time = int(input("Value to be used to increment the time period: "))

year = []

for x in range(min_time, max_time + 1, increment_time):
    year.append(x)

time_period = len(year)

n = []
for i in range(time_period):
    j = year[i]
    n.append(j)

print ("{0} {1}".format("Years: ", ""))
```

So what I want to do is, with those min_time, max_time, and increment_time variables use them to print out the appropriate number of columns.

An example:

If the user types in min_time = 1, max_time = 5, increment_initial = 1, I would want there to be columns for 1 through 5. Then on the next time if the user types in min_time = 1, max_time = 10, increment_initial = 1, I would want there to be columns for 1 through 10.

I hope I have made myself clear enough so you can understand what I am asking for.

Comment: what doesnt work in your current approach?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code. `year` and `n` will both be equivalent to `list(range(min_time, max_time+1, increment_time))`, and it's not clear what you want to be printing on a given row. Do you want `" ".join(str(x) for x in year)` or something?

Comment: lol are you currently enrolled in coursera?

Comment: I think the last few lines are irrelevant to your question. You copy `year` in `n` and then print `"Years: "`... from what I understood to your question you just want to do `for x in range(min_time, max_time, increment_time): print(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple different ways that you can build a row of output with a variable number of columns. Which one will be best may depend on what you're actually doing on a larger scale.

One simple approach is to loop over your column values and make a `print` call for each one with the keyword-only argument `end` set to something other than a newline. This will cause it to skip the usual newline at the end of the printed output. To get a newline at the end of the row, you'll need to make a regular `print()` call after all the columns have been printed.

Another option is to build a single string for your column, probably with `str.join`. Depending on how you want to format things, this might be `" ".format(str(x) for x in years)` or maybe something more complicated.

Here's code with both of those:

```
years = range(min_time, max_time + 1, increment_time)

for year in years:
    print(year, end=" ") # prints a space after each value, rather than a newline
print() # add a newline at the end of the row

row_str = " ".join(str(year) for year in years) # join year strings with spaces
print(row_str) # prints whole row in one step, with a newline at the end
```